# Quick help with regex in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Im not proficient in regex at all, but I need to strip IDs from urls, that are from a large block of text.

URL look like this:

domain.com/path/ID_GOES_HERE

The problem is, its inside emails, which come in a wide variety of formats ranging from:

```
- <a href="http://www.domain.com/path/ID_GOES_HERE">http://www.domain.com/path/ID_GOES_HERE</a>
- www.domain.com/path/ID_GOES_HERE
- http://domain.com/path/ID_GOES
_HERE
```

The ID is letters and numbers only. No other characters of any kind.

EDIT: 
Another issue is, since Im processing emails, which are horribly formatted, sometimes the URL ends up at the end of the line, where it gets broken up between 2 lines, which puts an equal sign at the end, like so:

```
http://www.domain.com/path/EE33FDE291A=
8D972
```

So the ID gets deformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
<?php
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('@domain\.com/path/((?:[a-z0-9_]|=\n)*)@i', $subject, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $id) {
    $id = str_replace("=\n", '', $id);
    // Do your processing here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^domain\.com\/path\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/', $text, $matches = array());
if(isset($matches[1]))
  echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Why use the caret and dollar sign if the domain could be anywhere within the string? Also, the OP said that only alphanumeric characters can be part of the ID, so the underscore doesn't need to be there.

Comment: Probably want more of what EdoDodo posted if there is more than one match per input. Just might want to add A-Z if the id can contain capital letters.

Comment: Thanks, removed the underscore. carat and dollar sign are to make matches[0] smaller :P I'm not sure if he wants one function to loop through a text with multiple matches then yours is correct. If he wants to search one block of text for one id and then search the next block of text etc. then mine is.

Comment: Yup, good point. And you're right, I forgot about capital letters. Made mine case insensitive now, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www.)?domain.com/path/([\d\w]+(?:\=?(?:\(?:[\r\n]|\r\n|)(?:[\d\w]+)?)?)/
```

seems to match all of your test cases